# Under Fedora 34 how to make the Artemis management console accessible?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a problem after installing Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.

I have created a new broker. It starts well but the management console is inaccessible outside the machine. However, Cockpit is accessible.
I'm a noob on Linux, but I'm looking to improve and understand

- apache-artemis-2.18.0
- Linux fedora 5.11.12-300.fc34.x86_64

Can you help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the embedded web server which runs the web console binds to `localhost:8161` which means it won't be accessible from a remote machine. The relevant configuration is in `etc/bootstrap.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
   <web bind="http://localhost:8161" path="web">
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
```

You can change the `bind` attribute to an IP address or hostname which is accessible to remote clients (e.g. `0.0.0.0`).

If changing the ActiveMQ Artemis configuration doesn't help then it may be an environmental issue. You should try disabling the firewall that ships with Fedora (i.e. [firewalld](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/firewalld/)).

Comment: And thank you for the answer. I just put the IP address in the bind attribute. But the console remains inaccessible to a remote client.

   <web bind="http://192.168.171.137:8161" path="web">
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
I don't understand why the Fedora Cockpit console works but not the Artemis management console.

Ports to open?. Stop the firewall?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely

Comment: Are you using `192.168.171.137` to access the Fedora Cockpit console?

Comment: Yes, https://192.168.171.137:9090. I try to modify jolokia-access.xml  <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin> and bootstrap.xml with  <web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
But still the same problems.

Comment: When you access `192.168.171.137:8161` from a remote machine what happens exactly? Does something load? If so, what is it? Does nothing load? Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? Are you running [firewalld](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/firewalld/) on your machine?

Comment: 1) Nothing load 2) This site is inaccessible, 3) ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, 4) systemctl disable firewalld. But still the same problems.

Comment: Sorry. systemctl stop firewalld. And restart it's work.
Thank you very much for your help